# ZF2 Navigation: Set UL id attribute

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2

I'm trying use the Navigation to build my menu. However, I need to set the id for the  tag

```
<ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/api">Api</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/a">Baker and spice</a>
    </li>
</ul>   '
```

But, I can't seem to do this.

I tried to build the html by using foreach

```
<?php 
foreach ($this->container as $page){ 
}
?>
```

It is not doing anything because $this->container is showing up as NULL.

Please advice!

Thanks in advance,

Justin

Comment: What are you using to define your navigation structure? Is it an XML file? PHP arrays? At some point in your app, you'll be creating the container and setting it as a view property, what does that code look like? Why is $this->container null? That seems unexpected, maybe solving that will let you solve the `id` problem?

Comment: I'm using the one defined in the zend tutorial. In module.config.php in application, I have the following:  ...    'navigation' => array(
        'id' => 'boo',
        'default' => array(
             array(
                 'label' => 'Home',
                 'route' => 'home',
             ),
             array(
                 'label' => 'Api',
                 'route' => 'api',
             ),
             array(
                 'label' => 'Baker and spice',
                 'route' => 'application',
             ),
        ),
    ),

Comment: In my view, I can simply call    echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu() to render the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your view you can call

```
echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu();
```

And that outputs your menu correctly, what you must be wanting to do is create a custom menu using a partial view script (hence why you're using `$this->container` which would otherwise not be set). To do this make sure you've got this:

```
echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()
          ->setPartial('my-module/partials/menu')->render();
```

And a corresponding partial script: a file named `menu.phtml` in the `module/MyModule/view/my-module/partials` directory (for this case).

```
// module/MyModule/view/my-module/partials/menu.phtml
<ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
<?php foreach ($this->container as $page): ?>
    <li <?= $page->isActive()? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>
        <?= $this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page) ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

(This gives you only a single-level menu, but will get you on the right path.)

Comment: Quick question, htmlify should return a string with an anchor tag. I changed my module.config.php so it has an extra filed controller and action. But the href in my anchor tag is built with 'route' (disregarding controller and action fields).

Comment: I was thinking, maybe $page is not casted correctly. I tried to do a var_dump($page) in menu.phtml, but, the page wouldn't render... Thanks in advance!

Comment: The route definition should dictate how these fields are displayed—if at all. E.g. route `'myroute[/:action]'` with `action == 'myaction'` should result in a URL `myroute/myaction`. I know the example I posted works, but if yours doesn't you should look at using a debugger to run through the code line by line.